# Initiate the template form with stored data

Tags: django

I collect user info with the following template:

```
<div class="row text-center vertical-middle-sm">
    <h1>Profile</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><span>Username:</span></div>
                <div class="col-md-8 text-left"><span>{{ user.username }}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><span>Gender:</span></div>
                <div class="col-md-8 text-left"><span>{{ user_profile.get_gender_display }}</span></div>
            </div>
```

In the view, there's lot of hardtyping to initiate the data:

```
else:
    user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
    user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(
                    initial={'birthday':user_profile.birthday,
                             'telephone':user_profile.telephone,
                             'school':user_profile.school,
                             'company':user_profile.company,
                             'profession':user_profile.profession,
                             'country':user_profile.country,
                             'about_me':user_profile.about_me,
                                })
    context = {"user_form":user_form,
               "user_profile_form":user_profile_form,}
    return render(request, "account/edit_profile.html", context)
```

How to refactor the `initial={}` shorter?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Your template does not contain a form at all. And you need to show the definition of UserProfileForm; is it also a ModelForm? If so why can't you use `instance=request.user.profile` like you did with UserForm?

Comment: This is perfectly an answer to my question. Could you help transmit it to answer for further reference. @DanielRoseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `initial` argument, as you do for UserForm.

```
user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
```